# Node positions in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to set up the following graph so that the 'old_view' & 'new_views' are at the same rank at the top, and 'old_submits & 'new_sub' are on the same rank at the bottom. 'Continues' would sit in between the two rows.

I've tried using subgraphs as suggested by others but it hasn't helped me on this one.

```
c=Digraph('parent')

c.attr('graph', label='')
c.attr('node',fontname='helvetica')
c.attr('graph',fontname='helvetica')
c.attr('edge',fontname='helvetica')
c.attr('node', shape='box', color='lightgrey')
c.attr(rank='same')

c.node('old_views')
c.node('new_views')
c.node('continues')


g=Digraph('subgraph')
g.graph_attr.update(rank='same')
g.node('new_submits')
g.node('old_submits')

c.edge('new_views','continues')
c.edge('continues','new_submits')
c.edge('old_views','old_submits')

c.subgraph(g)

c
```

Example image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A pure `graphviz` hint that you should be able to transfer to python easily:

If you want to "skip" a level, you have two possibilities (at least):

You can use an empty node - downside is that you have to define that empty node `b`, and that your edge pointing from `a` to `b` needs to have no arrowhead. Also, if you look carefully, you seen an empty pixel on the way from `a` to `c`.

The latter you can avoid by routing an extra invisible edge from `A` over `E` to `C`, creating not only the need for this extra edge but also for an increased weight on the`D -> E -> E` edge to keep it straight.

```
digraph so 
{
    b[ shape = point, width = 0]
    a -> b[ dir = none ];
    b -> c;
    d -> e -> f;

    A -> C;
    A -> E -> C[ style = invis ];
    D -> E -> F[ weight = 10 ];
}
```

The choice is yours!

[image]